# Cannot access Desktop/Space - switches back to the previous one

Tags: desktop, spaces, mission-control

I currently have 4 desktops/spaces and I thought I disabled everything to do with automatic rearranging them or switching to them.

Yet, sometimes macos insists on going back to a particular space driving me nuts. In the example below I move between `Desktop 1` > `Desktop 2` > `Desktop 3` using a keyboard shortcut but as soon as I reach `Desktop 3` I get sent back to `Desktop 1`.

In this particular case I discovered that what triggers it is one IntelliJ window on `Desktop 3`. I have multiple IntelliJ windows open on all my desktops but for some reason the one on `Desktop 3` causes the switch back to `Desktop 1`. If as soon as I reach `Desktop 3` I frantically `Alt+Tab` between windows so that IntelliJ window loses focus (not an easy feat) the desktop switching stops. Now, if I click on the IntelliJ window on `Desktop 3` I immediately get sent back to `Desktop 1` and the automatic switching reactivates...

Any idea how to truly disable the automatic switching for good?

macos monterey 12.3.1

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the Space affinity set to for IntelliJ? Spaces certainly doesn't like apps being spread over multiple Spaces, but I've never known it be quite this tenacious about it.

Comment: How can I check the Space affinity setting?

Comment: Right-click on Dock icon -> Options.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you meant now. As you may have guessed I never used this facility and so the assignment is set to 'None'. But I'll make sure to check this the next time this desktop switching happens, in case I somehow will have unknowingly changed the affinity.

Comment: 'None' should be the one with least 'fight' in it. I'm still not sure what happened - but it shouldn't :\ Let us know how you get on.